# How can I create an interface similar to an Excel spreadsheet on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, spreadsheet

I want to develop an iphone interface, using objective-c, which behaves like an Excel sheet.

It would display a grid which can be scrolled vertically as well as horizontally but during a vertical scroll, the first row will freeze, and during a horizontal scroll, the first column will freeze.

How can this be done?
I am new to iphone development.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the iPhone's UI classes, but here is what I would do from a conceptual point of view:

Create three separate scrollviews (rowLabels, colLabels, and grid), and then simply update the vertical scroll position of rowLabels and the horizontal scroll position of colLabels whenever the main grid view is scrolled in any direction.