# MS Excel type spreadsheet creation using objective-c for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a sample iOS app that generates multiple reports using data in the app.
Those reports looks exactly similar to Microsoft Excel spreadsheets like this.

[image]

How can I generate the similar using objective-c. I don't have any idea about how can I create the such grid-view. Do we have any objective-c supported framework or anyhting similar to `UITableView` to create such spreadsheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have never seen anything like this open source, and I don't think there is. So I would try to hand make it. I think there are three ways to go:

- **HTML**: This should be the easier way to go. Using a UIWebView to render some pre generated HTML/CSS you can create quite easily that spreadsheet (or even use a JS library).
- **Using a grid view**: Either using the Apple solution ([UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), since iOS 6.0) or a third party ([AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView),[GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView), etc. There are several, I have only used AQGridView, and its quite complete). The complexity here, is that this libraries are usually developed to show a grid of UIViews, so it's no easy to make them look like the spreadsheet you want.
- **CoreGraphics**: This is much more complex, as you need to draw all the lines, and then draw the fields, but is by far more flexible. I've developed a library for plotting a Radar Chart ([RPRadarChart](https://github.com/raspu/RPRadarChart)) using Core Graphics, and it wasn't that hard. I have a github repo with all the code that I used to learn Core Graphics, if you want, take a look at it:  [RPCGSandbox](https://github.com/raspu/RPCGSandbox)

Good luck, and if you find a better solution, please let us know.

Comment: fantastic answer dude.. pretty impressed with the explanation.. Accepted, upvoted & offered bounty to your answer. :) Awesome job. keep it up. Cheers coding

Comment: Will adopt for first way preferably.. but will decide after discussing with the team.. BTW I may poke you again if I need any help in future :p haha

Comment: @Vyacheslav 3 years ago (when this question was asked) they were still active... Nowadays UICollectionView replaced them.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a different solution to this issue, but so far I've found:
https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView

Looks like a spreadsheet, and has a similar interface to what a UITableView uses. I was looking for an alternative because the MDSpreadView doesn't use ARC, has a couple compiler warnings, and when I created a library project for it, I noticed it uses lots of images which do not get copied over by default.

Comment: Up-voted for your help. But how to use that library? There are no comments below on how to use

Answer (score 0):

You might want to dig deep into UICollectionView, UICollectionViewFlowLayout and also it would be worth looking into AutoLayout Constraints in iOS6. A helpful link : http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: I gone through `UICollectionView` a little but not finding them convenient. I wanted to know if there is anything similar to `UITableView` where we specify number of rows & sections with section header facility. I would specify number of rows & columns, column headers & then I can simply create the spreadsheet as per my requirement. If this is available & then it would be a cakewalk for developer

Comment: @Bikramjit Singh This solution is only for iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple tables as columns and when one scroll you scroll the rest of them as well. I create a grid using that and it was efficient to around 10000 rows and 20 columns. If you want i can guide you how will it be done.

Comment: Ummm.. Truly speaking I am not happy with the solution but still I would like to have guidance from you as you have said *it worked efficiently for you*.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder there is nothing you will find out of the box, you can create one to suite your needs that will do what you are looking for.