# How export UITableView data to excel in swift

Tags: swift, excel, tableview

I have an export history list data to excel in my project,the data is in the tableView ,what should i do

Comment: check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892174/ms-excel-type-spreadsheet-creation-using-objective-c-for-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

You can open a document in excel that is f.e. tab separated.

For example data in this form:

```
row1col1\trow1col2\trow1col3\nrow2col1\trow2col2\trow2col3
```

if saved as `.xls` can be opened with excel and will have this form:

```
┌────────┬────────┬────────┐
│row1col1│row1col2│row1col3│
├────────┼────────┼────────┤
│row2col1│row2col2│row2col3│
└────────┴────────┴────────┘
```